# Unity Gradle Build Fail

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, 64-bit

Im using Unity 2019.3.3f1 Personal and when i trying to build 64 bit i got 212 errors.
I think thats the most important one so i just pasting these:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.3f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[
D8: Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:407)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:244)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:66)
    ... 10 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 15s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>   Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
>
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:preDebugBuild
>   Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :launcher:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:processDebugManifest
>   Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugAssets
>   Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:mer

When im building 32 bit i can build perfectly.
Im dealing with that error over a week so please help :(

Comment: Please don't copy paste without thinking. You need to ask a clear question. Less is always better...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved with downgrading to 2018.4.14f and select internal build.